# select item in customize UITabBar in swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I add UITabbar with storyboard. And i have create 3 items in tabbar. (lets say "food", "sport", "videos") when i tap on "Food" items it open food view. And in uiTabbar "food" item is selected.

I have done first and last item with this code:

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?.first as? UITabBarItem
or 
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?.last as? UITabBarItem
```

These are work but in my project there is 3 items exist. And I can't select middle item. I try

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items[1] as? UITabBarItem
```

However doesn't work. I got this error

> '(UITabBar, didSelectItem: UITabBarItem!) -> ()' does not have a
>   member named 'selectedItem'

any suggestion?

Edit:
Solve by myself added the answer below

Comment: Where is this code? Please give us some more context.

Comment: I create single view project and i add uitabbar to my view on storyboard. As default, there is two item in tabbar when i add first time. So I add tab bar item(uitabbaritem) to my tabbar. As a result there are 3 item on my tabbar. And each of them are opening new viewcontroller. I give an example on original post. when i open food section. Then in tabbar i want to be selected on tab bar. There is not much code. I just drag tabbar and tabbaritem to my view.

Comment: @cVplZ ok, i just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for xx in (self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]){
            if xx.tag == 0 {
                self.tabBar.selectedItem = xx
                break
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not working for me... I am getting the error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Comment: If you know the index of the item already you don't need to loop. You can can just do self.tabBarView.selectedItem = self.tabBarView.items![tabToSelect] as UITabBarItem where tabToSelect is the 0 based index tabs

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:

`myTabBar.selectedItem = myTabBar.items![0]`